# How Can I Make A CALayer And All Its Sublayers Zoom Proportionally?

Tags: swift, core-animation, calayer, zooming, nsscrollview

I am trying to make an NSScrollView which displays document pages. I have added a CALayer-backed NSView as the NSScrollView's documentView, and then I have added a CALayer sublayer to the documentView. When I zoom the NSScollview, the documentView correctly zooms in and out. However, the sublayers of the documentView do not scale proportionally with their containing documentView. If I do not set an autoresizingMask on the sublayers of the documentView layer, the sublayers simply fly off the screen when the documentView is zoomed. If I use the LayerWidthSizable/LayerHeightSizable options, the sublayers get way larger or smaller than they should be in reference to the documentView superlayer. Here is the code I have so far:

Here is the NSScrollview:

```
class LayerScrollView: NSScrollView {

    var containerLayer: ContainerLayer!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        documentView = ContainerLayer(frame: frame)
    }
}
```

Here is the ContainerLayer (the documentView CALayer):

```
class ContainerLayer: NSView {

    let documentLayer: DocumentLayer = DocumentLayer()

    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        autoresizesSubviews = true
        wantsLayer = true
        layer = CATiledLayer()
        layer?.delegate = self
        layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.blueColor().CGColor
        layer?.masksToBounds = true
        documentLayer.frame = CGRect(x: frame.width / 4.0, y: frame.height / 4.0, width: frame.width / 2.0, height: frame.height / 2.0)
        documentLayer.delegate = documentLayer
        layer?.addSublayer(documentLayer)
        documentLayer.autoresizingMask = CAAutoresizingMask.LayerWidthSizable | CAAutoresizingMask.LayerHeightSizable
        documentLayer.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func drawLayer(layer: CALayer!, inContext ctx: CGContext!) {
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, NSColor.redColor().CGColor)
        CGContextFillRect(ctx, layer.bounds)
    }
}
```

And finally, here is the DocumentLayer (the sublayers contained in the DocumentLayer):

```
class DocumentLayer: CALayer {

    override func drawLayer(layer: CALayer!, inContext ctx: CGContext!) {
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, NSColor.redColor().CGColor)
        CGContextFillRect(ctx, layer.bounds)
    }
}
```

Here is a picture to illustrate the problem and my desired results:

[image]

The blue rectangle is the ContainerLayer, the red rectangle is the DocumentLayer.

I have looked through numerous tutorials and the documents and come up empty. It seems like this should be super-easy to do. What am I missing here?

Comment: Looks like the zoom transform is applied twice. Have you tried not to use CATiledLayer but a regular CALayer? Did you check what happens when you set bounds instead of documentLayer.frame ? Furthermore to help debug use borderWidth and borderColor so you see what the bounds of the layer actually are and the behavior is not coming from drawLayer. Also to dig into the issue you could log the transform property.

Comment: Thanks @mahaltertin. As it turns out, Apple recommends not setting frame or bounds directly for layers which are inside views being managed by Auto Layout, and the solution is to use constraints, but using the borderWidth property was greatly useful in debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE: SOLVED IT**

Here is the solution, found after more hours of digging through documentation and other stuff (also, thanks to @mahaltertin for suggesting that I use borderWidth to help debug):

The LayerScrollView:

```
class LayerScrollView: NSScrollView {

    var containerLayer: ContainerLayer!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        containerLayer = ContainerLayer(frame: frame)
        documentView = containerLayer
    }
}
```

The ContainerLayer:

```
class ContainerLayer: NSView {

    let documentLayer: DocumentLayer = DocumentLayer()

    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        wantsLayer = true
        layer = CALayer()
        layer?.layoutManager = CAConstraintLayoutManager.layoutManager()
        layer?.delegate = self
        layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.blueColor().CGColor

        documentLayer.delegate = documentLayer
        documentLayer.name = "documentLayer"
        documentLayer.borderWidth = 1.0
        documentLayer.backgroundColor = NSColor.redColor().CGColor

        documentLayer.addConstraint(CAConstraint(attribute: CAConstraintAttribute.Width, relativeTo: "superlayer", attribute: CAConstraintAttribute.Width, scale: 0.5, offset: 0.0))
        documentLayer.addConstraint(CAConstraint(attribute: CAConstraintAttribute.Height, relativeTo: "superlayer", attribute: CAConstraintAttribute.Height, scale: 0.5, offset: 0.0))
        documentLayer.addConstraint(CAConstraint(attribute: CAConstraintAttribute.MidX, relativeTo: "superlayer", attribute: CAConstraintAttribute.MidX, scale: 1.0, offset: 0.0))
        documentLayer.addConstraint(CAConstraint(attribute: CAConstraintAttribute.MidY, relativeTo: "superlayer", attribute: CAConstraintAttribute.MidY, scale: 1.0, offset: 0.0))

        layer?.addSublayer(documentLayer)

        layer?.setNeedsDisplay()
        documentLayer.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

And the DocumentLayer:

```
class DocumentLayer: CALayer {

    override func actionForKey(event: String!) -> CAAction! {
        return nil
    }
}
```

The solution is to use constraints. The override of the actionForKey method in the DocumentLayer is to prevent the DocumentLayer from animating while it zooms. The constraints defined in the ContainerLayer specify that the DocumentLayer should be half the width/height of the ContainerLayer, and that the middle of both layers should be the same. Zooming now keeps the proportions correct.

Comment: Did you import any library? Because I have this problem:  Use of unresolved identifier 'CAConstraint'

Comment: No - it has been some time since I posted this though so it is likely that an update changed naming somewhere.

Comment: @Carol, I received the same error today and found that `CAConstraint` is only available in macOS, not iOS. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1521899-addconstraint